# curl script working fine on a localhost but not giving the desired output on a live server

Tags: php, curl

The code below work perfectly on my local server but when i tried to access it on the live server, I got an unexpected output. Please your assistance will be much appreciated

```
function get_sub_status(){

    $curl = curl_init();
    $mobile_no='';
    curl_setopt_array( 
        $curl, 
        array( 
            CURLOPT_URL => "http://209.208.78.58:8085/dkm/api/verify/status.php?msisdn=234".$mobile_no,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true, )
                      );

    $response1 = curl_exec($curl);
    $response1 = JSON_DECODE($response1,true);

    curl_close($curl);


    if ($response1['status'] == "ACTIVE"){
        echo "Active";
    }else{
        switch ($response1) {
             case $response1['status'] == "ENDED";
                echo "Inactive";
                    break;
             case  $response1['message'] == "msisdn does not exist";
                echo "msisdn not found";
                    break;
        default :  
            echo "i got here";
        }
    }
}
get_sub_status();
```

Comment: What was the unexpected output? What is wrong?

Comment: i noticed that both active and invalid mobile no has an output "invalid" but on the local server everything work as expected

Comment: Can you post the json from a working api call?

Comment: Yes please {"id":"13234563","msisdn":"234","status":"ENDED","created_at":"2019-11-19 17:52:17","category":"0"}

Comment: That displayed Inactive as expected. I assume $mobile_no is filled in.

Comment: Have you check for any errors? Is curl installed on the server. I would check the web server log for any erros.

Comment: yes, curl is enabled on the live server and no error was found on the log_error